# How to use the godot::String % operator for string formating of multiple values?

Tags: c++, godot, godot-4

I tried this:

```
godot::String str = "values: %f,%f";
double a = 1.0;
double b = 2.0;
str = str % a % b;
```

Result string is:

```
"not all arguments converted during string formatting"
```

Documentation completely ignores that C++ exists and suggests the following GDScript:

```
var format_string = "%s was reluctant to learn %s, but now he enjoys it."
var actual_string = format_string % ["Estragon", "GDScript"]

print(actual_string)
```

The equivalent of this in C++ would be:

```
str = str % std::tuple(a, b);
```

But there is no operator for std tuple.

How can I format multiple values into godot string?

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code, `godot::String` does not seem to implement `%` overloading: [char_string.hpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-cpp/blob/master/include/godot_cpp/variant/char_string.hpp).

The [common_engine_methods_and_macros](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/core_and_modules/common_engine_methods_and_macros.html) documentation shows some common methods, including methods for formatting strings:

```
vformat(String("values:%f,%f"), 1.0, 2.0);
```

`godot:String` also implements a `format` method that accepts a `godot:Array` parameter:

```
String("values:{0},{1}").format(Array::make(1.0, 2.0));
```